# Sharepoint GetListItems()

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a website that requires the use of the Sharepoint webservices to obtain data stored in the calendar, when i call it the following way:

```
 System.Xml.XmlNode n = services.GetListItems("Calendar", String.Empty, null, null, null, null, null);
```

i only get data back for the previous month, current month and next month. what I want it to obtain all data stored in the calendar in the future and the past month.

I am new to Sharepoint webservices and have googled what I am trying to achieve but with no avail

---

In response to the answer and doing some more research I found the following page on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-Introduction) helpful which explains how to Select, Update, Insert and Delete items on a Sharepoint calendar using the Client Object Model.

Comment: Are you *sure* you want to use SharePoint Webservices? They were used only up to SharePoint 2007 and had lots of problems. In 2010+ you should use the Rest services and the client API. You should consider them obsolete, deprecated and all-but-unsupported

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos I'll have a look at the REST services and the Client API as i didn't know this option was available

Comment: You can use query expressions and LINQ with the client model to select only the items you need. Otherwise you'd have to create a CAML query that filtered the items you want - a big XML fragment that no-one wants to build by hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, what Panagiotis said - you should use the Client API.

Second, the SharePoint webservices by default ask the default view about data - this is probably filtered in your case. Create a (public) view that shows all items and pass this ViewID to your query.

P.S.: The Client API always returns all items - you don't need to define a view if you use this one.